# In Android, how can I change a color on a bitmap to another color?

Tags: android, colors, xor

I have a bitmap and want to be able to change all black pixels in that bitmap to blue. I know you can do this via Bitmap.setPixel but that process is extremely slow (believe me, I tried it...even doing the setPixels instead of setPixel).

Researching this is see where people recommend using PorterDuff Xor, but there isn't any posts on how this was successfully done. Lots of people asking...no one spelling out the answer.

So using, paint, bitmap, and canvas, how do you change every black pixel to all blue ones?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you make sure to use `getPixels` instead of `getPixel` as well? PorterDuff XOR should work, but it won't necessarily be that fast either.

Comment: while much more difficult, using NDK and doing bitmap manipulation in C code is the way to get high performance

Comment: I didn't try getPixels, just getPixel. I could do so I guess and see if it's fast enough. Was thinking the PorterDuff method was supposed to be fast but I cannot find even one example of it used to do this. I've been going down the ColorMatrix route for the last few hours but that doesn't seem to work when changing black to something. Only red, green, or blue to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just pull the pixels of the bitmap

myBitmap.getPixels(myPixels, 0 0, 0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight())

and loop over myPixels looking for whatever color you wish and modifying that pixel to whatever color you prefer.

Comment: That did it. Going to getPixels instead of getPixel. Thanks!